# Decimal Formatting issue python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Minor formatting issue: Im having trouble dealing with these kinda values:

```
97 $ 7.922816251426434e+26 
98 $ 1.5845632502852868e+27 
99 $ 3.1691265005705736e+27 
100 $ 6.338253001141147e+27
```

I want to make it print normally(?) with just 2 decimal places and the full number not the e+27 in the end..

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Are you sure they a floats? The format above is just scientific. If they are integers `'{:d}'.format(<very big int>)` would force them to print as integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

```
"%.2f" % value
```

Since python 3, you may as well use [string.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
"{:.2f}".format(value)
```

which looks more complicated, but is more modern and more powerful and worth getting used to ;)

Comment: im printing in this manner at the moment:

    print('Total Salary: ${}'.format(sum(pay)/100,'.2f'))

could you please show me how i could modify this..

Comment: First part is the "format string", which tells python how to format your values. You can put any string into it, and these `{...}` notations that are filled in with values. Inside the braces, after the colon, you can specify the format, e.g. ".2f" for fixed point numbers with 2 decimals after the point. Just like that:
`print("Total Salary: ${:.2f}".format(sum(pay)/100)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

'`{0:.2f}'.format(num)`

Explanation:

`{0}`tells format to print the first argument -- in this case, `num`.

Everything after the `colon (:)` specifies the format_spec.

`f` Fixed point. Displays the number as a fixed-point number. The default precision is 6.

Comment: Actually, `g` will format in scientific notation, i.e. the e+27 mode that OP does not want. Use `f` instead.

Comment: @opatut : `G` is for scientific notation not `g`. Both are different.

Comment: nope, type `"{0:.2g}".format(1e20)` into your interpreter, or read the docs. Both say otherwise. G is like g only uppercased :)

Comment: From the [`docs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)"G : General format. Same as 'g' except switches to 'E' if the number gets too large. The representations of infinity and NaN are uppercased, too."

Comment: My code for printing looks like this print('Total Salary: ${}'.format(sum(pay)/100,'.2f'))

how can i modify it in your way?

Comment: @sshekhar: Also from docs: "'g' ... and then formats the result in either fixed-point format or in scientific notation, depending on its magnitude." And the magnitude is around e+27, as you can see from above.

Comment: @user2405840: `print("Total Salary: {0:.2f}".format(sum(pay)/100))`

Comment: @opatut : Sorry, missed that part :) Edited my answer

Comment: I get the error: "ValueError: cannot switch from automatic field numbering to manual field specification"

Comment: See my answer. Remove the "0" before the colon.

Comment: Daaaaaaaaaaaaaymmmmmnnnnnnnnnnn, thank u cap'n.. u rock my boat :)